# Notes and Attachments, conversion to Files SOQL

Tags: attachment, files, migration

I converted all Notes and Attachments which are associated to Case object to Files. When I run a SOQL query on ContentVersion to see all the Files, I don't see all the files.

Case has Public Read/Write/Transfer sharing setting. Can any one tell me what mistake I am making. I used Salesforce Notes and Attachment Magic Mover to move all attachments to Files.

Here is the SOQL which i am using:

```
SELECT Description,FileExtension,FileType,Id,Title FROM ContentVersion
```

Comment: Where is your SOQL? Share it please by editing your question and placing your relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

There are unique features to data access with `ContentVersion`. In particular, the "View All Data" permission does not apply.

From the [ContentVersion reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm):

> Users (including users with the “View All Data” permission) can only query files they have access to, including:
>   * All Salesforce CRM Content files in libraries they're a member of and in their personal library, regardless of library permissions (API version 17.0 and later).
>   * All Salesforce Files they own, posted on their profile, posted on groups they can see, and shared directly with them (API version 21.0 and later).

You can obtain all `ContentVersion` data by using the Scheduled Data Export feature with the export attachments feature turned on.

Comment: In addition, I found this as well-  "Depending on how files are shared, queries on ContentDocument and ContentVersion without specifying an ID won't return all files a user has access to. For example, if a user only has access to a file because they have access to a record that the file is shared with, the file won't be returned in a query such as "SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument."   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm